# DataRow row = dt.Rows[0]; //There is no row at position 0 indexoutofrangeexception

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GVRAgencyConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select      weight,mrp_pack,no_of_pack,mrp_master_pack from dbo.purchase_order where   product_ID=@product_ID",con1);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_ID", DropDownList3.Text);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con1.Close();           
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
            txtwgt.Text = row["weight"].ToString();
            txtmrpsinglepack.Text = row["mrp_pack"].ToString();
            txtnoofmasterpack.Text = row["no_of_pack"].ToString();
            txtmrpmaster.Text = row["mrp_master_pack"].ToString();
```

Comment: This error means that your database table `purchase_order` does not contain any records having  `product_ID` equals to the selected value in `DropDownList3`. What is the problem?

Comment: You should write something about what you are trying to do, and what your problem is, not just post some code and an error message. The error message that you show is actually the expected result in your situation.

Comment: Thank u sir please help me sir if i need help in programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) try this :

2)welcome to StackOverFlow.

3) *you cant move to live with some girl if you dont have a girl.*

Same here - you cant touch with records in datatable withindex 0 if you dont know that you already have rows in index 0.

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GVRAgencyConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select      weight,mrp_pack,no_of_pack,mrp_master_pack from dbo.purchase_order where   product_ID=@product_ID",con1);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_ID", DropDownList3.Text);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con1.Close();           
             if (dt.Rows.Count==0) return;
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
            txtwgt.Text = row["weight"].ToString();
            txtmrpsinglepack.Text = row["mrp_pack"].ToString();
            txtnoofmasterpack.Text = row["no_of_pack"].ToString();
            txtmrpmaster.Text = row["mrp_master_pack"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result is empty, so there are no rows at all in the data table.

You can check this before trying to access the row:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)  {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
string selectquery = "SELECT TITLE,DESCRIPTION,SEVERITY,STATUS,IMPACT,USER_NAME AS CREATED_BY ,CREATED_DATE FROM Issues A, USERS B  Where  A.CREATED_BY=B.USER_ID AND A.ISSUE_ID=" + ID;
//string selectquery = "SELECT TITLE,DESCRIPTION,USER_NAME AS ASSIGNED_TO,SEVERITY,STATUS,IMPACT,USER_NAME AS CREATED_BY ,CREATED_DATE FROM Issues A, USERS B  Where  A.CREATED_BY=B.USER_ID AND A.ASSIGNED_TO=B.USER_ID AND A.ISSUE_ID=" + ID;
OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(selectquery, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
//GridView1.DataSource = dt;
// GridView1.DataBind();
lblTitle.Text = dt.Rows[0]["TITLE"].ToString();
lblDescription.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
//lblSeverity.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
lblStatus.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
lblStatus.CssClass ="status"+ dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
//lblImpact.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
lblCreatedby.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
lblcreateDate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CREATED_DATE"].ToString();
//blCommentsDescriptionresult.Text = txtCommentdescription.Text;
```